Keras in R / RStudio - Extracting labels from tensor flow dataset
I have a tensorflow test dataset of images. I've made predictions using a CNN model for binary classification on the test dataset (predictions), but need to create a confusion matrix from those predictions. To do that, I need to extract the labels from my tensorflow dataset (read from my directory as two folders of image files, each folder belonging to one class). Intuitively I think I need to convert my tensorflow dataset to an R array so I can extract the list of image files by label (and presumably this will be a vector in the same order as the predictions were made), but I can't find a way of doing that using a number of different R-Python interface packages, e.g. rTorch, tfdatasets, etc.
Help would be much appreciated!

I don't think it is necessary to convert the TensorFlow dataset to an R array to extract the labels. The tfdatasets package in R allows direct interaction with TensorFlow datasets. You can iterate over the dataset and extract labels directly from each batch without the intermediate step of converting the dataset to an R array.
You could try running code similar to this:
library(keras)
library(tfdatasets)
library(caret)

test_dataset <- image_dataset_from_directory(
  "path_to_test_data",
  label_mode = "int",
  batch_size = 32,
  image_size = c(224, 224)
)

# Iterate over the dataset and extract the labels:
# In a real world case it would be better to vectorise 
# the following block. In particular, using c() to 
# build the label vector is not advisable but will 
# suffice for the sake of this example.

get_labels <- function(dataset) {
  labels <- c()
  for (batch in as_iterator(dataset)) {
    batch_labels <- batch[[2]]$numpy()
    labels <- c(labels, batch_labels)
  }
  return(labels)
}

test_labels <- get_labels(test_dataset)

# Make predictions
predicted_labels <- model |>
  predict(test_dataset) |>
  as.array() |>
  (\(x) ifelse(x > 0.5, 1, 0))()

conf_mat <- confusionMatrix(as.factor(predicted_labels), as.factor(test_labels))

